# Which is correct subject verb agreement: 'Two miles IS/ARE a long distance'?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

- > two miles **is** a long distance

or

- > two miles **are** a long distance

I would like to explain to my students clearly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do you say "Fifty miles IS ......"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13950/why-do-you-say-fifty-miles-is) ...... and [100 apples are/is considered as a large number of apples](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145690/100-apples-are-is-considered-as-a-large-number-of-apples)

Comment: Try flipping the sentence around: "A long distance is/are two miles."… There is only one *distance*, which is 2 miles long by measure.